# Prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\{x \in M : d(x, A) ≥ \epsilon \}$ is a closed set in $(M, d)$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Say that $(M, d)$ is a metric space, and $A$ is a subset of $M$. For each $x \in M$, $d(x, A)$ means $inf\{d(x, y) : y \in A\}$.
I'm trying to prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\{x \in M : d(x, A) ≥ \epsilon \}$ is a closed set in $(M, d)$.

I've seen the open set proof on this site for less than $\epsilon$, but can't see how that correlates to this proof.

Comment: A subset $A$ is closed if and only if its complement $A^c$ is open. You say you've see the proof that $\{x\in M : d(X,A) <\epsilon\}$ is open, so it follows that the set you ask about is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(M, d) $ be a metric space and $A\subset M$

$d(x, A) =inf \{d(x,a):a \in A \}$

Define a function, $d_A: M\to R $ by $$d_A(x) =d(x, A) \space \space [\forall x\in M]$$

Then the function is continuous on $M$.

Because, given any $\epsilon >0$,choose $0<\delta <\epsilon $

$|d(x, A) -d(x', A) |<d(x, x')<\epsilon$ whenever $d(x, x') <\delta$

Now, we know pre-image of closed set under continuous map is also closed.

Choose, $F=[\epsilon, \infty) $ closed set in $(\mathbb{R}, d_{usual}) $

Then, $d^{-1}_A [\epsilon,\infty)=\{x\in M : d(x, A) \ge \epsilon \}$
is closed set in the space $(M, d) $